# Why does the for loop update expression (i + 2) create an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I was doing an exercise in my textbook that asked us to output a vector's elements at even indices separated by asterisks. Then on a newline, do the same thing with the odd indices. So, if the vector contained `10 20 30 40 50 60`, the output should be:

```
10*30*50*
20*40*60*
```

The textbook gives us the starting code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int numStudents;
   int i;

   cin >> numStudents;
   vector<int> idNumbers(numStudents);

   for (i = 0; i < idNumbers.size(); ++i) {
      cin >> idNumbers.at(i);
   }
```

And we need to finish the code. My initial solution was:

```
// Even indices
for (i = 0; i < idNumbers.size(); (i + 2)) {
   cout << idNumbers.at(i) << "*";
}
cout << endl;

// Odd indices
for (i = 1; i < idNumbers.size(); (i + 2)) {
   cout << idNumbers.at(i) << "*";
}
cout << endl;
```

But this produced an infinite loop. So I then changed it to:

```
// Even indices
for (i = 0; i < idNumbers.size(); i++) {
   cout << idNumbers.at(i) << "*";
   i++;
}
cout << endl;

// Odd indices
for (i = 1; i < idNumbers.size(); i++) {
   cout << idNumbers.at(i) << "*";
   i++;
}
cout << endl;
```

Which did give me the correct output.

If I recall correctly from my first programming class, the update expression doesn't need to increment by one. So, why did my first solution not work, but the second solution did?

Comment: It, (i +2), doesn't alter the value of i. Perhaps you meant i +=2?

Comment: You used `i + 2` to in an attempt to add 2 to `i` but what you need to write is `i += 2`

Comment: @AviBerger @Wyck Oh I see! I forgot that I need to reassign `i` just like any other variable. Thank you guys!

Comment: Side note about the starter code: While `at` is often a good idea when testing and debugging, there is a small performance hit in the extra bounds check it performs. When  the code cannot possibly go out of bounds like in `for (i = 0; i < idNumbers.size(); ++i) { cin >> idNumbers.at(i); }` because `i` is forced in bounds by `i < idNumbers.size()`, the extra `at` checking is detrimental. In addition, be careful defining `i` outside the loop because it could be used or misused by code outside the loop and deliver surprises.

Comment: I have 20 € in my wallet. 20 + 100 is 120, tada now I have 120 € in my wallet. Unfortunately it doesnt work like that ;)